# Formatting numbers in python

Tags: python, input, formatting, numbers, format

I am struggling to format some numbers in my python program. The users enters three numbers and then I put them into a formula. For example when the following numbers: 1 2 3, are entered on the command line, the output should look like this: 
 x**2+2x+3 = 0

Instead I am getting this: 1.0x**2+2.0x+3.0 = 0

How do I format it to loose the end decimals? I just want it to print out what was submitted. Here is some of my code:

```
    a = float(sys.argv[1])
    b = float(sys.argv[2])
    c = float(sys.argv[3])

    #to format equation
    equation = ("{}x**2{}x{}".format(a,b,c))
```

Comment: and if `a` is 0, would you like `2x+3` ?

Comment: Perhaps you should google "formatting numbers in python".

Comment: `"I just want it to print out what was submitted."` - Then just don't convert to `float`?

Answer (score 0):

Just use int instead of float

```
import sys

a = int(sys.argv[1])
b = int(sys.argv[2])
c = int(sys.argv[3])

#to format equation
equation = ("({}x**2)+({}x)+({})".format(a,b,c))

print equation
```

I tried : python myfile.py -1 -2 3

**output:**

(-1x**2)+(-2x)+(3)

Comment: Then it won't work for floats. It would work if op only wants integers.

Comment: @Someone OP wants simple int as he stated x**2+2x+3 = 0.s

Comment: would this allow negatives though?

Comment: He did not state it, he just said he wants to remove unnecessary decimal places. He might not want to remove them if the number is not an integer.

Comment: @user3093377 yes negative numbers also works. you can try it

Answer (score 0):

you can type cast variable while formatting.

```
    a = float(sys.argv[1])
    b = float(sys.argv[2])
    c = float(sys.argv[3])

    equation = ("{}x**2{}x{}".format(int(a),int(b),int(c)))
    print equation
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone elses answer doesn't allow for float inputs. There are 2 ways of doing this that I can think of:

```
a = float(sys.argv[1])
b = float(sys.argv[2])
c = float(sys.argv[3])

equation = ("{}x**2+{}x{}".format(str(a).rstrip('0').rstrip('.'),str(b).rstrip('0').rstrip('.'),str(c).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')))
print equation
```

This one takes away a `0` and a `.` from the end of each number if it exists.

```
a = float(sys.argv[1])
b = float(sys.argv[2])
c = float(sys.argv[3])

equation = ("{}x**2+{}x{}".format(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])
print equation
```

This one inserts exactly what the user inputted into the equation.